# Number of ways to fill a $2\times n$ grid with $1\times 2$ and $2\times 2$ tiles

Tags: combinatorics, induction, tiling

> How many ways are there to  fill a $2\times n$ grid with $1\times 2$ and $2\times 2$ tiles? Rotating is allowed.

#### Progress

Let $T_n$ be the number of ways; then $T_n = T_{ n-1} + T_{ n-2} + 1 $ (based on removing one of tiles, as in quid's answer).

Comment: Usually, in problems like this, you would try a few cases (say for $n$ from $1$ to $4$ or $6$ or something), and see if you can spot some pattern. Next, you would use that pattern to come up with a guess at a formula. _Then_ comes the induction part of the proof, showing that the formula you have is indeed correct. You should at least try the cases yourself before coming here.

Comment: i guess the formula is this : T(k) = T(k-1) + T(k-2) + 1 . the parentheses are indices

Comment: Good. Together with $T(1)=1$ and $T(2)=3$, does that formula work for $k=3$ or $4$?

Comment: i guess it does

Comment: How do you arrive at your formula? Did you have a look at my answer?

Comment: yes i did something so similar to yours , but i cant go any further :D

Comment: Okay. So given my answer it seems the recusion is $T(n-1) +2 T(n-2)$, and $T(1)=1$ and $T(2)= 3$ Is this a sufficient answer or do you want something else?

Comment: i know that but i want to prove it for k+1

Comment: What do you want to prove? This is a recursive description of the sequence? Do you want a more closed form? (There is one but it is not very nice/)

Comment: ok thanks i did the rest . thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the end (or start) there are three possibilities:

- $2 \times 1$ tile.
- $2 \times 2$ tile.
- two $1 \times 2$ tiles.

Removing these last tiles yields:

- a tiling of $2 \times (n-1)$ grid.
- a tiling of $2 \times (n-2)$ grid.
- a tiling of $2 \times (n-2)$ grid.

From this, and the first values, you get the recursive description that you can solve if you want something more explicit.

---

**Added for the record:**

- The recursion is $T_n = T_{n-1} + 2T_{n-2}$ and $T_1= 1$ and $T_2=3$.
- This sequence is known as [Jacobsthal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_number), except for a shift of the index.
- The closed form is $$\frac{2^{n+1} - (-1)^{n+1}}{3}.$$

Comment: Should be $T_n=T_{n-1}+2T_{n-2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I schould have paid more attention when typing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of a combinatorial interpretation of the closed form?  (I may ask that as a separate question...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki OEIS has several applications http://oeis.org/A001045 I would not know a "bijective proof" of the current problem at the moment. (But this does not tell much.)