# Why does this application of Jacobsthal numbers defined by the recurrence relation: $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$ + 2$a_{n-2}$ work in 2D tiles / grids?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, tiling

Problem Statement: Find the Recurrence Relation for $a_n$, where $a_n$ is the number of ways to tile a (2xn) rectangular board with (1x2) or (2x2) pieces.

.
.

*Note:* A (1x2) piece can be placed either vertically or horizontally

.
.

The solution to this question goes like this:

Considering the last column(s) of the board: There are 3 cases.

- filled by (2x2) piece - i.e. there are $a_{n-2}$ ways remaining
- filled by (1x2) piece which is placed horizontally - i.e. there are $a_{n-2}$ ways remaining
- filled by (1x2) piece which is placed vertically - i.e. there are $a_{n-1}$ ways remaining

**Therefore**, $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$ + 2$a_{n-2}$

.
.

As much as this line of reasoning makes sense, when I sub n=3 into $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$ + 2$a_{n-2}$, the number of grid squares for $a_n$ is 6 while the number of grid squares for $a_{n-1}$ + 2$a_{n-2}$ is 8? [image] **This makes me wonder whether there is a better visual intuition of the recurrence relation: $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$ + 2$a_{n-2}$ since the Jacobsthal number sequence is originally for 1D number sequence?**

Comment: @RobPratt Hmm thanks for sharing, not really actually, let me try to edit my question

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066650/number-of-ways-to-fill-a-2-times-n-grid-with-1-times-2-and-2-times-2-tiles

Comment: @RobPratt Hmm okay, I have edited my question again not sure if my updated question makes any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=3$, let's use your numbering

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The first case corresponds to removing the $2\times 2$ 2356 tile, leaving

```
1
4
```

and there is only $a_{3-2}=a_1=1$ way to complete the tiling.

The second case corresponds to removing the horizontal 23 and 56 tiles, leaving

```
1
4
```

and there is only $a_{3-2}=a_1=1$ way to complete the tiling.

The third case corresponds to removing the vertical 36 tile, leaving

```
1 2
4 5
```

and there are $a_{3-1}=a_2=3$ ways to complete the tiling.

So $a_3 = 2a_{3-2}+a_{3-1} = 2 a_1 + a_2 = 2\cdot 1 + 3 = 5$.